# Mobile Menu Bar not working Bootstrap Template

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

For some reason, my mobile menu is not working. Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class='container'>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" id='navbar-toggle' class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="brand">
        <a href="../index"><img src="assets/img/transparentlogo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
 
            <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="contact" class="book">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this post!

Comment: You do not have </ul> </div> </div> at the end of your code if you are running the above code as it is.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add that part, I will edit the question.

Comment: Did you remember to add the path to the css file for the classes you are using for the elements in your nav bar menu?

Comment: um, so you asked did i do this? <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> if so, i did add it

Answer (score 0):

if you used bootstrap 4.6 or some lower version chenge the jquery version and after that chenge the your jquery place in your end of your body for example

```
  <script src="....................."></script>
  <script src="....................."></script>
     <script src="your jquery"></script>
```

now cheng the place

```
     <script src="your jquery"></script>
  <script src="....................."></script>
  <script src="....................."></script>
```

Comment: But where do I put the script source? Also, I don't have any of the script src="...." things you are showing.

Comment: top of end html tag when your html be closed betwen body and html at last